# Where should I reset the timeElapsed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform target;
    public bool turnOnOffPlayerAnimator = false;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float lerpDuration = 3;
    float startValue = 1;
    float endValue = 0;
    float valueToLerp = 0;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private bool entered = false;
    private bool resetElapsed = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (turnOnOffPlayerAnimator)
            playerAnimator.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (IsFacing(target))
        {
            if (entered)
            {
                if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                {
                    valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                    playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (valueToLerp < 0.9f)
            {
                if(resetElapsed == false)
                {
                    timeElapsed = 0;

                    resetElapsed = true;
                }

                if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                {
                    valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                    playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            }
        }

        if(turnOnOffPlayerAnimator)
        {
            playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerAnimator.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        entered = true;

        Debug.Log("Entered !");
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        entered = false;

        Debug.Log("Exited !");
    }

    private bool IsFacing(Transform target)
    {
        Vector3 forward = player.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 toTarget = target.position - player.position;
        return Vector3.Dot(forward, toTarget) > 0;
    }
}
```

I reset it once back to value 0 in this part :

```
if(resetElapsed == false)
                    {
                        timeElapsed = 0;
    
                        resetElapsed = true;
                    }
```

but it also working only once.
I need somehow to reset the value to 0 each time the player is switching direction facing or not facing the target but not sure where and how to do it in the Update.

if not resetting it to 0 when the player will not facing the target or will face it after not facing again the value of timeElapsed is bigger then the lerpDuration value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the result of your IsFacing() method in a field and check in the next update run if it's has still the same value.

Simple example:

```
private bool prevFacing = false;

void Update() {
  var currFacing = IsFacing(target);
  if(currFacing != prevFacing) {
    // here you switched from facing to not facing or vise verca.
  }
  prevFacing = currFacing;
}
```